# Bundle Randomly goes into GracePeriod

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, blueprint-osgi, aries

I have a persistence bundle, most of the time it works perfectly fine, but every once in a while it gets stuck in `GracePeriod`, when that happens, the missing dependency is the `EntityManager`:

```
karaf@root>bundle:diag 237
framework-connect-persistence (237)
 -----------------------------------
Status: GracePeriod
Blueprint
2/27/17 2:48 PM
Missing dependencies:
(&(osgi.unit.name=PersistenceUnitPrimary)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))
```

But, as you can see, there IS an `EntityManager`

```
karaf@root>service:list EntityManager
[javax.persistence.EntityManager]
 ---------------------------------
osgi.unit.name = PersistenceUnitPrimary
service.bundleid = 237
service.id = 427
service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
framework-connect-persistence (237)
```

Restarting the bundle doesn't change anything. However restarting the bundle `org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint` fixes the issue

Any ideas ?

Thank you

EDIT :

[bundle:list](https://pastebin.com/raw/tqXzyBec)

[feature:list](https://pastebin.com/raw/DW1h4fUU)

[MANIFEST.MF](https://pastebin.com/raw/qtg7M10w)

[logs](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hraf/ecfb33211be99aa90a5c58c364b1e6d9/raw/b9b7f4e84b96be1422ed6927db8d3d25016276ec/servicemix.log)

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><persistence version="2.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">  

<persistence-unit name="ConztanzEntityManagerFactoryPrimary" transaction-type="JTA">            
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=ConztanzDB)</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>            
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode"   value="auto"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.conztanz.persistence.dialect.PostgreSQLConztanzDialect"/>n setting -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"      value="com.conztanz.persistence.jta.ConztanzJtaPlatform"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql"         value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql"       value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more info: which version of Karaf you use, output of bundle:list and feature:list, manifest of your bundle and contents of persistence.xml

Comment: I just updated the post with the relevant information

Comment: Last attempt. Could you please post your Karaf log file after you reproduced the issue?

Comment: You mean after restarting the org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint bundle or before ?

Comment: I mean right after the moment when you face the bundle coming in grace period

Comment: I just added the logs

Comment: I am not sure, but I see the Hibernate error in your logs, and it makes me think that it may be the root cause of the issue. Could you please this this and try again to reproduce:

Comment: 2017-04-06 13:45:33,025 | ERROR | pool-61-thread-1 | MetadataContext                  | 283 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : com.conztanz.model.person.contact.Phone_#tagSet

Comment: I'm certain that's not the root of the problem, I had the GracePeriod issue long before the static metamodel field error